# ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I can't seem to find `ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged` in ef core. Has this been removed and if so what is the alternative?

I want to be notified whenever an entity is loaded into the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (the latest official EF Core v1.1.2) there is no public alternative. There are plans to expose [Lifetime Hooks](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/626), but according to [EF Core Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap) they are postponed and will not be available in the upcoming v2.0 release.

Luckily EF Core exposes all the internal infrastructure classes/interfaces, so I could suggest the following workaround under the typical EF Core internals usage disclaimer

> This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.

What I have in mind is utilizing the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal` namespace, and more specifically the `ILocalViewListener` interface which provides the following method

```
void RegisterView(Action<InternalEntityEntry, EntityState> viewAction)
```

The `viewAction` allows you to register delegate which will be called on any entity state change, including attaching, adding, deleting, detaching etc.

So inside your `DbContext` derived class constructor, you could obtain `ILocalViewListener` service and register the handler like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
    public MyDbContext()
    {
        this.GetService<ILocalViewListener>()?.RegisterView(OnStateManagerChanged);
    }

    void OnStateManagerChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState previousState)
    {
        if (previousState == EntityState.Detached && entry.EntityState == EntityState.Unchanged)
        {
            // Process loaded entity
            var entity = entry.Entity;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the handler, you can also use the `InternalEntityEntry.ToEntityEntry()` method to get the regular `EntityEntry` object (similar to `DbContext.Entry` and `ChangeTracker.Entries` methods) if you prefer working with it rather than the internal `InternalEntityEntry` class.

Tested and working in EF Core v1.1.2.

Comment: Great answer. Works like a boss. Small correction  entry.ToEntityEntry().Entity gives you the regular entity. Would have given you the bounty already, but SO says I have to wait 12 hours.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :) What about `ToEntityEntry`, I meant to get the "normal" `EntityEntry` object to work with (rather than the `InternalEntityEntry`). But `InternalEntityEntry` has `Entity` property providing the regular entity as well, so `ToEntityEntry` is really arbitrary.

Comment: Indeed :). I just meant to add that entry.ToEntityEntry().Entity gives you the actual entity from your domain.

Comment: This lib might help as well https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers/