# Is it possible to intercept a READ action?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core, you can override `SaveChanges`/`SaveChangesAsync` method in the `DbContext` and based on different states like: `EntityState.Added` or `EntityState.Modified` or `EntityState.Deleted`, you can create some Audit solution about when and whom created, modified or deleted certain records. You can save the state of the entity before and after the action. All good here works perfect!

Can we do something similar for read/query/select/view actions?

Comment: Why this should be closed? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132553/objectstatemanager-objectstatemanagerchanged-in-entity-framework-core/45192985#45192985 could help

Comment: By this you mean how to log SELECT statements or something different?

Comment: A bounty doesn't magically turn a question into a *clear* question.

Comment: @GertArnold: What's not clear? In the DbContext you can override the SaveChanges and intercept operations like Add, Update, Delete, therefore you can Audit your data. User A created record Y, User B updated record Y, User C deleted record Y, etc, etc etc. My question is how we can audit read data like User X viewed/read/opened record Y? Isn't this a valid audit requirement to know who has viewed specific records that are maybe secret or private? My question was if we can do this somehow in the same way as for Creat, Update, Delete events or has to be done within the application.

Comment: You got a question that you didn't answer. You didn't mention why the built-in logging (`ILoggerProvider` etc.) apparently doesn't suffice. Now you suddenly bring a user into play. Too many things that may be obvious to you, but not to others.

Comment: Doesn't `audit` explain itself? Should I have brought a definition of audit? There it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audit_trail. Of course user is part of an audit otherwise why bother? My question doesn't have to do anything with ILoggerProvider but about EF, and intercepting certain events, and wanted to know if there can be traced also read event same way as we do for Create, Update, Delete? EntityFramework specific question. Otherwise yes ILoggerProvider is the way to go.

Comment: What User do you mean? database user, your web application user? If web application user - it is not EF specific question.

Comment: Ok this seams to be pretty hard question. I will edit it!

Comment: I really REALLY don't want to nag you, but it's still not clear what you want to audit. The number of records *modified* in a transaction will probably be limited, but one user can easily *read* thousands (or more) records by simply opening one UI function. Do you want do audit all these records individually? I *think* you have to audit read actions on a selection of aggregate entities like: "user A opened file X at time Y" but not all read actions of data belonging to the file and (maybe) not even the read actions that lead to opening the file (f.e. querying a file list).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dug a little and found that the actual execution of the `IQueryable` is done by `EntityQueryProvider : IAsyncQueryProvider, IQueryProvider`.

So... you override the default `EntityQueryProvider` to do the logging:

```
   public class LoggingQueryProvider : EntityQueryProvider
    {
        public LoggingQueryProvider(IQueryCompiler queryCompiler) : base(queryCompiler) { }

        public override object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            var result = base.Execute(expression);
            //log
            return result;
        }
        public override TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            var result = base.Execute<TResult>(expression);
            //log
            return result;
        }
        public override IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            var result = base.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(expression);
            //log
            return result;
        }
        public override Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = base.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(expression, cancellationToken);
            //log
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and you register it when configuring DbContext in `StartUp.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
    services.AddDbContext<XPContext>(builder =>
        builder
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration["TryDBConnectionString"])
        .ReplaceService<IAsyncQueryProvider, LoggingQueryProvider>()
    );
```

It's not quite straight forward, but you should be able to get some information from the expression, like the entity type, and you obviously have access to the actual result. Things look a bit more complicated for the async methods, but...

Comment: I like the idea of extending the query provider, but how are you planning on logging to the db without the dbContext?

Comment: Brilliant answer, the same / similar way can be used to modify the entity while reading from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Most strategies rely on overriding `SaveChanges()` to audit data, but you can access other data by overriding the `Dispose()` method as well.

When data is queried from the database it is added to the dbContext and if it is read but not changed it should have `EntityState.Unchanged`.

Assuming a typical web app style `DbContext` scope of a new instance per request then a query by id would mean that there was a single entry in the `ChangeTracker` with that state when the `DbContext` is disposed.

You could try something like this:

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    var unchanged = ChangeTracker.Entries()
          .Where(x => x.EntityState == EntityState.Unchanged);

    // log your unchanged entries here

    base.Dispose();
 }
```

This is not totally foolproof, as you might retrieve data from some tables as part of validation during a create/update process, or you might share a context across multiple repositories so you need to consider what entities need auditing carefully and what access patterns you use

Comment: What about queries with `AsNoTracking()`?

Comment: @GertArnold As I said - not foolproof. Assumes OP has control over all queries. Now that you mention it `AsNoChangeTracking()` could add a fine grained method of excluding some queries from auditing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest logging at a higher level. For example, if you're using a WebApi you can log at the OWIN pipeline level thereby logging the requests for information.
Logging lower ends up second guessing and re-iterating through data which is ugly and will end contributing to inefficiencies.