# How to log reading from a(any) table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In my project we want the ability to log who has viewed a particular table(or any table). Now I am not looking to log SQL queries, rather I am looking for the most generic way to log (much like logging updating and deleting) who has read (viewing) data. I execute either something builtin to Entity Framework or I execute custom code I write. I am not sure which is best or considered best practice.

Here is an example of a normal get

```
public List<DataModel.Table1> GetTable1(int Id1, int Id2)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext(base.GetContext))
    {
        var x = (from s in context.Table1
                 where s.Id1 == Id1 && s.Id2 == Id2
                 select s).ToList();
        return x;
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to log who has done this. Either in say the BL(or in this call) I then pass down another call to the data access layer with another model or is there a built in way to log the table name, the primary key that were retrieved and the user who did it that is built into Entity Framework. I know there is for updating and such. But I'm not sure about reading (or viewing).

Here is a little something I cooked up as an example. Below, is this how I would do it? If so can I set it up a little bit nicer or cleaner. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public List<DataModel.Table1> GetTable1(int Id1, int Id2)
            {
string y =  context.Database.Log.Target.ToString();
                using (var context = new MyContext(base.GetContext))
                {
                    var x = (from s in context.Table1
                             where s.Id1 == Id1 && s.Id2 == Id2
                             select s).ToList();
List<DataModel.ViewLog> views = new List<DataModel.ViewLog>();
                foreach (DataModel.Table1 f in  x)
                {
                    DataModel.ViewLog v = new DataModel.ViewLog
                    {
                        TableName = y,
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        ViewedByEmployee = "",//ill get this somewhere else or pass it down
                        PkIdViewed = f.Id1
                    };
                    views.Add(v);
                }
                DataAccess.ViewLog viewLog = new                 DataAccess.ViewLog();
                viewLog.LogView(views);//saves everything in the list
                    return x;
                }
            }
```

Edit. Note I am looking for a centralized solution so that I don't have to copy paste the little blurb of code in every single get method I have and second it should allow for any table to be logged not just one.

Comment: Does this offer a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867613/is-it-possible-to-intercept-a-read-action

Comment: @jeroenh I will have to run through that real fast. Possibly. Of course when I googled searched I never got that which is annoying. Nor was it in the suggested already asked drop down when I created the question but let me try it.

Comment: That's why we're here also, to look for similar questions together and help each other. No worries ;-)

Comment: @jeroenh Not quite its the right idea I guess and its closer than what I posted but he is using entity core I am not. So it doesn't quite work.