# Entity Framework Core: Adding a new entry in a 'join' table deletes existing records

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Some code removed for brevity.

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC website using Entity Framework Core.

I have three tables for `Parts`, `Distributors` and `DistributorParts` (join table).  On my site, I have a page to add `Distributors` to a `Part`.  When I create a new `DistributorPart` record for **Distributor 1** and **Part 1**, the record is inserted correctly. But when I add a second `DistributorPart` record for **Distributor 2** and **Part 1**, the first `DistributorPart` record is deleted!  (note that the two aforementioned `DistributorPart` records are both using **Part 1**)

My questions are:

- How can I get new `DistributorPart` records to be inserted **without** deleting/affecting the existing records?
- What am I doing wrong?

Models:

```
public class Part
{
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DistributorPart> DistributorParts { get; set; }
}

public class Distributor
{
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DistributorPart> DistributorParts { get; set; }
}

public class DistributorPart
{
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OnHand { get; set; }

    public int OnOrder { get; set; }

    public int PartId { get; set; }

    public Part Part { get; set; }

    public int DistributorId { get; set; }

    public Distributor Distributor { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `DbContext`:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Distributor> Distributors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<DistributorPart> DistributorParts { get; set; }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) 
        : base(options) 
    { }
}
```

Here is the code the inserts the new `DistributorPart` record:

```
public DistributorPart AddDistributorPart(DistributorPart distributorPart)
{
    var newDistributorPart = new DistributorPart
    {
        OnHand = distributorPart.OnHand,
        OnOrder = distributorPart.OnOrder,
        PartId = distributorPart.PartId,
        DistributorId = distributorPart.DistributorId
    };

    _context.Add(newDistributorPart);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return newDistributorPart;
}
```

I can verify this in the Application Output window when debugging:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed
>   DbCommand  (1ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?', @p1='?', @p2='?'],
>   CommandType='Text',  CommandTimeout='30'] DELETE FROM
>   "DistributorParts" WHERE "Id" = @p0; ...

**EDIT:**

Here's my Controller method that calls the AddDistributorPart() method:

```
public DistributorPart AddDistributorToPart([FromBody] DistributorPart distributorPart)
{
    var part = _partService.GetPart(distributorPart.PartId);
    if (part == null || part.Id <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Part Id of {distributorPart.PartId} does not exist.");
    }

    var distributor = _distributorService.GetDistributor(distributorPart.DistributorId);
    if (distributor == null || distributor.Id <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Distributor Id of {distributorPart.DistributorId} does not exist.");
    }

    var userId = GetUserId();
    var newDistributorPart = _distributorPartService.AddDistributorPart(distributorPart, userId);

    ...

    return newDistributorPart;
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct. What do you see when you check the `DistributorParts` table? The rows actually on that table?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. There must be something not shown in the post.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, thanks!  I just deleted all data in the DistParts table to start fresh. When I add a new record to the DistributorPart table, I have Id of 15, partId 1, DistributorId 1.  When I add another record for PartId 1 and DistributorId 2, the previous record with Id 15 is deleted from the database and Id 16 is in its place (only one record appears, incremented PK).  What the heck!

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks!  I think you're right, but I cannot find what's going on.  From what I've researched, I think my migrations are correct when setting up the table, as the relationships appear correct, but EF is deleting the records, as I show in the Application Output above.  Is there any other code I can provide that you think may be helpful?

Comment: Since the `_context` variable seems to be shared between different calls (and even different repositories or whatever helper classes you use, it's hard to tell where to look. Can you put a breakpoint before the `_context.Add(newDistributorPart);` line and examine `var deletedEntries = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity is DistributorPart && e.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();` and see if it's empty?

Comment: @IvanStoev, yes, that list is empty.  I cleared out my Application Output window, and I still see the delete occurring (I an inserting a new record into a different table, not mentioned above for brevity, called InternalPartNumber): [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
 Executed DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?', @p1='?', @p2='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
 DELETE FROM "DistributorParts"
 WHERE "Id" = @p0;
 INSERT INTO "InternalPartNumbers" ("Created", "Description")
 VALUES (@p1, @p2)
 RETURNING "Id";

Comment: @IvanStoev, I removed the filtering on State == Deleted, and I see that there are two entries for DistributorPart. The 1st entry is the existing record in the database with state of Modified (although I'm not modifying it at all).  The 2nd entry is the new one I'm saving to the db with state of Added.  Why would there be two entries when I'm simply adding a new one?

Comment: In EF every little detail matters. I would suggest you providing trimmed down, but reproducible example model and code. If you create a new clean project with just information provided in the post currently, you'll see that it doesn't happen.

Comment: Regarding your last response: I wanted to see the change tracker state **before** calling `Add` so there should not be entity with state `Added`. And no `Modified` or `Deleted`. Then do the same **after** `Add` call. Just trying to figure out if the `Add` method is causing the weird thing or there is something *before* it :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, sorry, just realized I put that tracker after the add but before the .SaveChanges().  I just added a tracker to the first line of the AddDistributorPart() method, and it does have an entry in the list with Modified state.  That's really odd... I'm going to add that tracker in the PartsService.GetPart() method called from the Constructor (pasted that Ctor code as an edit of this post).

Comment: Np. Here is what you can do. Take [my answer to ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132553/objectstatemanager-objectstatemanagerchanged-in-entity-framework-core/45192985). Inside `OnStateManagerChanged`, add breakpoint with condition `entry.Entity is DistributorPart && entry.EntityState == EntityState.Modified`. When the breakpoint is hit, examine the call stack to see what code is causing it.

Comment: Holy cow!  I think I figured out what's going!  In that PartsService.GetPart(), the code that was pulling the Parts looks like this: `var part = _context.Parts.Where(p => p.Id == id).Include(p => p.DistributorParts).FirstOrDefault();` I added the 'Include()' so that it would populate a collection/list of DistributorParts.  When I comment out the .Include(), it works as expected. But with the .Include(), the tracking code says DistributorParts is in 'Modified' state. Any idea what's going on, @IvanStoev?  Thanks again!!!

Comment: Except if there is some EF Core bug I'm unaware of, `Include` cannot put entity in a modified state. I believe that's happening from some other operation. Try the suggestion from my previous comment, the call stack should really give you the information about what operation is causing it.